# Select most recent date and most recent clock

Tags: mysql

How do i get the 3 most recent dates and clocks ?
Its not possible to use current_timestampp atm, so i need to fetch id 5-4-3, by ordering dato & clock desc.

```
id|dato|clock

1|2015-02-10|10:48
2|2015-02-10|10:49
3|2015-02-10|10:50
4|2015-02-11|10:48
5|2015-02-11|10:49
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY dato DESC, clock DESC
LIMIT 3
```

[RUN TEST](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f15455/1)

Comment: Oh thank you alot. Id used >ORDER BY dato, clock DESC